# Use of "to lunch" vs."for lunch"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is right?

> I went to the (mall) to meet my parents **for** lunch / **to** lunch

This for a paper I am submitting for a writing assignment. I have heard "to lunch" is right, but is it right in this sentence please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is it wrong if I say _I went **for** lunch to meet my parents_.

Comment: No, it's not wrong

Comment: Actually, we should ask OP for clarification. OP could have meant something like "I went to the X to meet my parents (for lunch)/(to lunch)." Meaning, the phrase in question would go at the end, not where X is. X would stand for a generic place like a mall or something. It's not impossible :)

Comment: @Max ahh you might be right there. I'll fix it. The OP has probably done a runner,

Answer (score 5):

This is an example where it's not a matter of one preposition being right while the other is wrong. Either preposition would form a grammatical sentence.

To understand why, it's important to note that the word *lunch* can be used as a noun or as a verb:

[image]

Therefore, in this sentence:

> I went to the mall to meet my parents to lunch.

the phrase *to lunch* is being used as an infinitive, while in this sentence:

> I went to the mall to meet my parents for lunch.

the word *lunch* is being used as a noun.

Though both are grammatical, most of the time, I would recommend using *for*, not *to*. Using *lunch* as verb often sounds rather stilted, particularly at the end of a sentence like in this case.

Comment: The unpretentious *to skate* doesn't sound all that great in *I went to the mall to meet my parents to skate,* so it's probably the case that something more is involved than stilted language.

Answer (score 0):

*To X*, among many other things, generally identifies or "points to" X as the target of a motion or action.

> I went to the (mall) to meet my parents to lunch

This sounds like you are trying to say that your parents are somehow being moved toward or thrown to a lunch.  It doesn't make sense.

*To X* is also a sign of the infinitive, but you need a "link" between "to meet my parents" and "to lunch".  Infinitives function as nouns in sentences, and if "to lunch" is an infinitive above you just have two random nouns in a row.

It's like saying this:

> I went to the store milk.

You need a relation between "store" and "milk" for that sentence to mean anything.

---

*For X*, among many other things, generally identifies X as a reason or purpose.

> I went to the mall to meet my parents *for* lunch.

You are meeting your parents, and the purpose of that is *for lunch.*  This is expressed properly.

Comment: RE: _This sounds like you are trying to say that your parents are somehow being moved toward or thrown to a lunch. It doesn't make sense._ I'm not sure it's quite so awkward. Consider this: "I went to the church to meet my parents to sing. We are performing a trio next Sunday." Or this one: "I went the pool to meet my roommate to swim." (Granted, I'd probably say, "I went to the pool to swim with my roommate" instead, but I don't know where this notion of being "thrown to a lunch" came from.)

Comment: You're right, *to X* can be short for *in order to X* or *so we could X.*  But not *so we could have X.*  I guess really then what rubs me the wrong way is that *lunch* just sounds weird to me as a verb without "do".  I don't hear people use it as a verb without "do" or "have" too often.

Comment: @LC - Yes, I agree, and I allude to that in my answer. It's grammatical, but it's odd, and it might get you some funny looks.